# Obtener resultado de consulta ordenado

Tags: sql, sql-server, tsql

La pregunta parece muy sencilla pero no he logrado resolverlo. En un SQL Server 2012 después de varias operaciones obtengo el siguiente resultado donde supuestamente son las ventas de Enero y Febrero

```
DECLARE @Tabla AS Table (Grupo varchar(3),Cliente smallint,anyo smallint, Enero float,Febrero 
float, Total float)

INSERT INTO @Tabla VALUES 
('A',100,2022,1,20,21)
,('A',100,2023,20,10,30)
,('B',110,2022,5,5,10)
,('B',110,2023,10,10,20)
,('B',120,2022,10,15,25)
,('B',120,2023,10,20,30)
,('B',130,2022,10,1,1)
,('B',130,2023,10,1,1)

SELECT * FROM @Tabla ORDER BY Grupo,Cliente,Anyo
```

como podéis ver el resultado está ordenado pero no es así como lo necesito y os explico:

```
DECLARE @Tabla2 AS Table (Grupo varchar(3),Cliente smallint,anyo smallint, Enero float,Febrero float, Total float)
INSERT INTO @Tabla2 VALUES 
 ('A',100,2022,1,20,21)
,('A',100,2023,20,10,30)
,('B',120,2022,10,15,35)
,('B',120,2023,10,20,30)
,('B',110,2022,5,5,10)
,('B',110,2023,10,10,20)
,('B',130,2022,10,1,1)
,('B',130,2023,10,1,1)
```

aquí como podéis ver dentro del grupo B primero está el cliente 120 porque dentro del año actual 2023 es el que tiene las mayores ventas totales.

He tratado de obtenerlo usando todas las posibles combinaciones de Grupo,Cliente y Anyo y nada, no he podido, ¿ me ayudáis ?, ¿ algún forma para lograrlo que no sea con el ORDER BY ?

Muchas gracias de antemano

Comment: No entiendo muy bien el orden que quieres. Podrías explicarlo?

Comment: La pregunta es un poco confusa, porque te refieres a resultados cuando en los bloques incluyes sentencias declarativas y consultas. Es difícil deducir qué queries has escrito y qué resultados has obtenido que no se ajustaban a tus objetivos y en qué aspectos concretos esos resultados no satisfacían tus requisitos.

Comment: pongo los dos bloques para que con los selects sea más fácil ver los datos que obtengo y los que quiero obtener en lugar de escribirlos directamente en la pregunta

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Interpretando un poco el sentido de tu pregunta, deduzco que buscas un resultado que ordene los registros obtenidos de manera **DESCendente** por `Total` y has probado diferentes configuraciones de la consulta sin éxito. Particularmente en relación con la `@Tabla2` intuyo que has debido de probar una consulta parecida a la siguiente:

```sql
SELECT *
FROM @Tabla2
ORDER BY Grupo ASC, Cliente ASC, Anyo ASC, Total DESC
```

Pero, naturalmente, el resultado de esta no arrojará el orden DESCendente en relación al campo `Total` de la manera que estás buscando, no importa si la especificación del comando `DESC` es perfectamente válida:

```swift
+-------+---------+------+-------+---------+-------+
| Grupo | Cliente | Anyo | Enero | Febrero | Total |
+-------+---------+------+-------+---------+-------+
| A     |     100 | 2023 |    20 |      10 |    30 |
| A     |     100 | 2022 |     1 |      20 |    21 |
| B     |     120 | 2022 |    10 |      15 |    35 |
| B     |     120 | 2023 |    10 |      20 |    30 |
| B     |     110 | 2023 |    10 |      10 |    20 |
| B     |     110 | 2022 |     5 |       5 |    10 |
| B     |     130 | 2022 |    10 |       1 |     1 |
| B     |     130 | 2023 |    10 |       1 |     1 |
+-------+---------+------+-------+---------+-------+
```

La razón es sencilla, si prestas atención a los (demasiado numerosos) criterios de ordenación en cascada utilizados. Al anteponerse los criterios de `Cliente` y `Anyo` a la instrucción para ordenar por `Total` de manera descendente, aquellos dos campos tienen prioridad en la operación de ordenación y el criterio que está en último lugar es más probable que devenga inútil, especialmente en *datasets* pequeños. Dicho de otra manera: el criterio de ordenación descendiente por `Total` sólo podría llegar a apreciarse en este ejemplo en los casos de registros de idéntico Grupo, Cliente y Anyo, una coincidencia que en este *dataset* por cierto no existe.

La solución para hacer efectiva la ordenación por `Total`, conservando la ordenación por `Grupo` que deduzco que también forma parte de tus requisitos es por tanto cargar con menos cartuchos la batería de criterios de ordenación:

```sql
SELECT *
FROM @Tabla2
ORDER BY Grupo ASC, Total DESC;
```

Resultado:

```swift
+-------+---------+------+-------+---------+-------+
| Grupo | Cliente | Anyo | Enero | Febrero | Total |
+-------+---------+------+-------+---------+-------+
| A     |     100 | 2023 |    20 |      10 |    30 |
| A     |     100 | 2022 |     1 |      20 |    21 |
| B     |     120 | 2022 |    10 |      15 |    35 |
| B     |     120 | 2023 |    10 |      20 |    30 |
| B     |     110 | 2023 |    10 |      10 |    20 |
| B     |     110 | 2022 |     5 |       5 |    10 |
| B     |     130 | 2022 |    10 |       1 |     1 |
| B     |     130 | 2023 |    10 |       1 |     1 |
+-------+---------+------+-------+---------+-------+
```

Comment: muchas gracias @alejandroMAD, no lo había "visto" tan claro antes de tu explicación, el campo cliente en la ordenación sobra, algo tan sencillo y que no logré darme cuenta